# Acceso a servidor WSL 2 desde internet o red local

Tags: ubuntu, wsl

Soy nuevo en Stack Overflow y es mi primer post, asique cualquier error que tenga hacédmelo saber para corregirlo.
Mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo montado Ubuntu a través de WSL 2 y me gustaría poder acceder a el desde fuera, tanto desde internet como desde otros dispositivos de la red.
Investigando un poco, parece que las conexiones de la versión 2 de WSL ya no pasan por el anfitrión (windows) al usar su propio kernel, por lo que desde Ubuntu tengo acceso a internet pero al lanzar un servidor web apache, por ejemplo, no puedo acceder desde fuera, solo a través de localhost.

He intentado poner el adaptador ethernet de WSL en modo bridge desde el administrador de Hiper V, pero haciendo eso me quedo sin internet en la máquina virtual, al hacer ping a google.com, por ejemplo, me da error de dns.
También he probado con el siguiente comando:
"netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=80 connectaddress=172.19.16.1", luego añadiendo una regla al firewall de windows para permitir las conexiones en el puerto 80.
Esto ha funcionado a medias, cuando realizo un escaneo de puertos con http://whatsmyip.org el puerto 80 aparece abierto, sin embargo no puedo conectarme ni a 192.168.0.XXX desde otro dispositivo de la red, ni a mi ip pública desde fuera, además que la ip del adaptador de Hiper V cambia tras cada reinicio, con lo cual no es muy práctico tener que estar cambiando todas las reglas cada vez que inicio la máquina.

La verdad que ya no sé por donde seguir.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Según lo que yo he visto, las conexiones en WSL2 funcionan como si estuvieran en el anfitrión. Por ejemplo si la IP del anfitrión es 192.168.1.10 y tienes algún servicio web corriendo en WSL en el puerto 8000, serás capaz de verlo desde 192.168.1.10:800. Algo que debes de tener en cuenta es cómo hacer el inicio del servicion dentro de WSL. Si lo haces especificando `localhost` o la IP equivalente, no podrás acceder. Algunos recomiendan usar `0.0.0.0` en su lugar, de este modo podrás acceder desde otros lados en la misma red.

Comment: Una vez que logres acceder dentro de la misma red, para el tema de acceder desde otros puntos (no en la misma red) debes asegurarte de que los puertos de tu modem/raouter esten apuntando a los del equpo en los que corre tu aplicación.